# Using value object as ID in Spring data jdbc - unable to insert

Tags: spring, domain-driven-design, spring-data-jdbc

I am trying to use the PartyId ( a value object) as Id in spring data JDBC. I am setting the value in PartyId (you can see in first screen shot below), but at time of inserting it gives following error.

[image: PartyId debug image]

**Debug Screen shot of cause**

[image]

**Stack Trace**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL 

[INSERT INTO "party" ("currency_uom_id", "description", "party_id", "party_type_id", "status_id", "version") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; ERROR: null value in column "party_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, Organisation, USD, Enable, 1).; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "party_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, null, Organisation, USD, Enable, 1).
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:251) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1541) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:991) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:340) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.insert(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:138) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.executeInsertRoot(JdbcAggregateChangeExecutionContext.java:90) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.AggregateChangeExecutor.execute(AggregateChangeExecutor.java:66) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
```

The error says , PartyId is null , which violets the db constraints.

**Party Class as Aggregate Root**

```
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
public class Party  implements AggregateRoot   {
    //Business key Id;
    @Id//Use by spring data jdbc
    @Embedded(onEmpty = USE_NULL)
    private PartyId partyId; // private String partyId - this is working (removing @Embedded also)
    private String description;
    @Embedded(onEmpty = USE_NULL)
    private PartyTypeId partyTypeId;
    @Embedded(onEmpty = USE_NULL)
    private CurrencyUomId currencyUomId;
    @Embedded(onEmpty = USE_NULL)
    private StatusId statusId;

    @Version
    private long version;
    /*private List<PartyAttributes> partyAttributes = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<PartyCarrierAccount>   partyCarrierAccounts = new ArrayList<>();*/

     //Only package level access
     public Party(PartyId partyId,String description,PartyTypeId partyTypeId,CurrencyUomId currencyUomId,StatusId statusId,List<PartyAttributes> partyAttributes,List<PartyCarrierAccount> partyCarrierAccounts){
         this.partyId = partyId;
         this.partyTypeId = partyTypeId;
         this.currencyUomId = currencyUomId;
         this.statusId = statusId;
         
    }
```

The insert will work if I make partyId as String (private String partyId in Party class, obviously removing @Embeded annotation from partyId)

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data JDBC does not yet supports embedded ids. But since your `PartyId` seems to contain only a single value, you can register a custom conversion for it and get the result you want.

[Here is an example for registering conversions.](https://github.com/schauder/talk-beyond/tree/master/src/main/java/de/schauderhaft/beyond/conversion)

You create a configuration class like the following

```java
@Configuration
static class ConversionConfigurationApplication extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public JdbcCustomConversions jdbcCustomConversions() {
        return new JdbcCustomConversions(asList(PartyIdToString.INSTANCE, StringToPartyId.INSTANCE));
    }


    @WritingConverter
    enum PartyIdToString implements Converter<PartyId, String> {

        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public String convert(PartyId source) {
            return source.partyId;
        }
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    enum StringToPartyId implements Converter<String, PartyId> {

        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public PartyId convert(String source) {
            return new PartyId(source);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I configured the converts , but getting this error 

org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.gerps.UserServices.domain.partybc.party.PartyId!
 at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:79) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
 at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.extendBy(BasicJdbcConverter.java:403) ~[spring-data-jdbc-2.1.6.jar:2.1.6]
 at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.BasicJdbcConverter$ReadingContext.read

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest version and try again? Although it should work with the version you are using. If it still doesn't work, please file an issue with a reproducer.

Comment: The relevant issue that introduced this is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/571

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
     @EmbeddedId   //have not found onEmpty parameter in any documentation 
     private PartyId partyId;
   ```
2. ```
    @Embeddable
    public class PartyId
   ```
3. Override `equals` and `hashcode` methods on `Party class` to consider the `partyId` field.
4. go to `PartyId class` and override `equals` and `hashcode` methods to consider all id fields of class `PartyId`

Comment: I am not using Spring Data JPA (I know how to use value object in JPA), its Spring Data JDBC.